# Using Awk to create a csv line

Tags: sed, awk

I am new to awk and can't quite figure out the best way to do this.
I have thousands of xml files which I have already removed duplicates and divided fields into a single column in a single file using sed and awk.

Now I want to assemble the list into a csv file containing multiple fields on one line. After a fixed number of fields I want to start a new line.

Example

```
1234
2345

345678
4.23456E3
54321
654321
789

87654.100
9876

10.0
1234
2345

345678
4.23456E3
54321
654321
789

87654.100
9876

11.0
```

Output

```
1234, 2345, , 345678, 4.23456E3, 54321, 654321, 789, , 87654.100, 9876, , 10.0
1234, 2345, , 345678, 4.23456E3, 54321, 654321, 789, , 87654.100, 9876, , 11.0
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is using `xargs` allowed?

```
cat input | xargs -L13 -d'\n' | sed -e 's/ /, /g'
```

I get this output here:

```
1234, 2345, , 345678, 4.23456E3, 54321, 654321, 789, , 87654.100, 9876, , 10.0
1234, 2345, , 345678, 4.23456E3, 54321, 654321, 789, , 87654.100, 9876, , 11.0
```

It's sort of hackey, though, if you started out with XML you should consider using XSLT.

Comment: Use `xargs -a input` instead of `cat`.

Comment: @Dennis: Or `xargs ... < input`. But the reason I used `cat` there is because he made it sound as if he wants something to put at the end of an existing pipeline, and I wanted that usage to be clearer.

Answer (score 2):

If every line would have the same number of fields, say, 5, I would do something like

`awk ' { printf("%s",$1); if (NR % 5 == 0) {printf("\n")} else {printf(",")}}' youtfile.txt`

NR is the number of lines read by awk and % is the remainder operator. So if the number of lines read is a multiple of 5 (in this case) it will print a line break, otherwise it will print a comma.

This assumes one field per line as in your example and that blank lines in the input will correspond to blank fields in the CSV.

Answer (score 2):

One way using `sed`:

Content of `script.sed`:

```
## Label 'a'
:a

## If last line, print what is left in the buffer, substituting
## newlines with commas.
$ {
    s/^\n//
    s/\n/, /g
    p   
    q   
}

## If content of buffer has 12 newlines, we have reached to the limit
## of the line, so remove newlines with commas, print and delete buffer
## overwritting it with 'b'
/\([^\n]*\n\)\{12\}/ {
    s/^\n//
    s/\n/, /g
    p   
    b   
}

## Here buffer has not reached to the limit of fields for each line, so
## append one more (N) and continue loop in label 'a'
N
ba
```

Run it like:

```
sed -nf script.sed infile
```

With following output:

```
1234, 2345, , 345678, 4.23456E3, 54321, 654321, 789, , 87654.100, 9876, , 10.0
1234, 2345, , 345678, 4.23456E3, 54321, 654321, 789, , 87654.100, 9876, , 11.0
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you:

```
paste -sd',,,,,,,,,,,,\n' file | sed 's/,/, /g'
1234, 2345, , 345678, 4.23456E3, 54321, 654321, 789, , 87654.100, 9876, , 10.0
1234, 2345, , 345678, 4.23456E3, 54321, 654321, 789, , 87654.100, 9876, , 11.0
```

or this (GNU sed):

```
sed ':a;$bb;N;s/\n/&/12;Ta;:b;s/\n/, /g' file
1234, 2345, , 345678, 4.23456E3, 54321, 654321, 789, , 87654.100, 9876, , 10.0
1234, 2345, , 345678, 4.23456E3, 54321, 654321, 789, , 87654.100, 9876, , 11.0
```